# Derivative of transpose

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, transpose

I am trying to find derivative of this :
RQ(u) = u<sup>T</sup>X<sup>T</sup>Xu / u<sup>T</sup>u

I need help finding derivative : RQ/u

Optimal sol should satisfy X<sup>T</sup>Xu = RQ(u)u

I am very confused, any help would be great. If you could share some references that will be very helpful too.

Comment: Are you sure about $XTXu = RQ(u)u$? This means that **every** vector is an eigenvector of $X^T X$, which implies $X^TX$ is a multiple of the identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity you are interested in is known as the [Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient). We have

$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{u^T X^T X u}{u^T u}
= \frac{1}{u^T u} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^T X^T X u) + (u^T X^T X u) \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^T u)^{-1}
$$

Now use $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} u^T A u = 2Au$ for symmetric matrix $A$:
$$
\implies\frac{\partial}{\partial u} RQ(u)
= \frac{2X^T X u }{u^T u} - \frac{ (u^T X^T X u) 2 I u}{(u^T u)^2} = \frac{2}{u^T u }\big(X^T X - RQ(u)\cdot I\big)u
$$

In particular, if $u$ is a maximizer/minimizer of $RQ$ then

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} RQ(u) \implies \big(X^T X - RQ(u)\cdot I\big)u =0 $$

If you are unsure about the matrix derivatives, I recommend this online tool: http://www.matrixcalculus.org/, and for fomulas [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) and [The Matrix Cook Book](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the resources.

Answer (score 1):

We have $ y = u^T X^T X u $. We compute the differential of $ y$
$$
dy = (du)^T X^T X u + u^T X^T X (du)  \\
dy = Tr ((du)^T X^T X u + u^T X^T X (du))  \\
dy = Tr ( u^T X^T X (du)) + Tr( u^T X^T X (du) ) \\
dy = 2 Tr ( u^T X^T X (du)) \\
dy = 2 (u^T X^T X)^T: du
$$
Finally $dy/du = 2 (u^T X^T X)^T = 2 X^T X u $

**Additional information**
Here I have used two properties of the trace:
1) $ Tr(ABC) = Tr(BCA) = Tr(CAB) $
2) $ Tr(c) = c $, where $c$ is an scalar

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You did not consider the demonitor? u^Tu and how about without Trace?

Comment: Oops, I did not see it...